# Huge performance issue after migration

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb

I am moving some of my websites to another service since I want higher performance. I did the first relocation of one website yesterday and encountered a huge unexpected drop in response time.

The websites are equivalent:
https://nordfro.webease.net (old hosting provider)
**Largest Contentful Paint 1.8s (GTMetrix)** [Full report here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16JmfumyQ4oysPQJG6KTgbmrOrYwIdjDL/view?usp=sharing)
https://nf.ahh.nu (new hosting provider, should theoretically be faster)
**Largest Contentful Paint 5.5s (GTMetrix)** [Full report here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16QT633m4mjQCXsFPoGMbqqgJWo8V830D/view?usp=sharing)

The slowness seem to be due to something happening on server side that GTmetrix can’t analyze properly.

I noticed that the new hosting provider is using MariaDB instead of MySQL (old provider) and I started to research this and understand that the issue could very much be here and that the migration did something with the data. My knowledge does not go much further than this though and I need help to dive deeper.

**EDIT #1:**

The first environment is a shared reseller hosting with access to 100% vCPU. The new hosting got 200% vCPU which is also the reason for moving since that makes most sense with Litespeed Caching. Ping gives the same 35-40ms on both servers.

This is the hosting provider info of the old environment:
https://buyshared.net/cpanel-reseller-hosting/

Whilst this is the new environment (10G):
https://nexusbytes.com/web-hosting#hosting-features

**EDIT #2:**

The MariaDB config (at least what was shared to me):

```
wait_timeout = 3600
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1024M
query_cache_size=128M
```

Comment: Drop in performance... how exactly? And what are the specs of the old/new hosts (and locations)?

Comment: is there a difference in the config from MySQL / MariaDB ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen I have access to DirectAdmin and PhpMyAdmin, can I find the config-files there? I have no /etc/ in the file managar. I have asked both of my hosting providers to share the conf-file with me.

Comment: What is the ping time to each?  Niue is in the Pacific, quite far from anyone not on that island.  Get the "ping" time from your client.

Comment: @RickJames .NU is now controlled by a Swedish institution and there shouldn’t be anything real about that it was once formally from that Island in the pacific. Ping time is 35-40 ms on both servers.

I have seen your input earlier on the forum, Rick, and saw that you made a comment about LONGTEXT in another migration to MariaDB. Could this be something to look into?

My first service provider suggest that I should do a full migration from DirectAdmin to DirectAdmin, is that a good idea?

Comment: How **exactly** did you measure the performance?

Comment: @NicoHaase I added some more info about that now. Thanks for helping me clarify.

Comment: How much RAM on each server?  What are the timings when you avoid the Query Cache?  (see SQL_NO_CACHE).  (I don't know anything about DirectAdmin.)

Comment: Time To First Byte seems to be the main issue.  What DNS server were/are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that the database is to blame for this problem? How did you check for other problems? Can you share the benchmark you are using?

Comment: Additional information request, please.  Data from OLD server and NEW server, please.
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.